# Weird behaviour of pandas' `.xs` method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
key,date,col   
s1,2018-01-21,1.0
s1,2018-02-23,1.0
s1,2018-04-24,0.0
s1,2018-05-25,0.0
s2,1993-01-09,1.0
s2,1993-01-09,1.0
s2,1993-01-09,1.0
"""

d = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
d['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d['date'])
d.set_index(['key', 'date'], inplace=True)
d.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
d 

Out[4]: 
                col
key date           
s1  2018-01-21  1.0
    2018-02-23  1.0
    2018-04-24  0.0
    2018-05-25  0.0
s2  1993-01-09  1.0
    1993-01-09  1.0
    1993-01-09  1.0
```

The next line gives expected results:

```
d.loc[(slice(None), '2018'),:]

Out[5]: 
                col
key date           
s1  2018-01-21  1.0
    2018-02-23  1.0
    2018-04-24  0.0
    2018-05-25  0.0
```

But the following code gives rather unexpected results, it selects a row with year 1993. Why does this happen? I would rather it threw an error saying it couldn't find the index.

```
d.xs('2018', level=1, drop_level=False)

Out[6]: 
                col
key date           
s1  2018-02-23  1.0
    2018-04-24  0.0
    2018-05-25  0.0
s2  1993-01-09  1.0
```

Just to add as per the comment below, I am on Fedora 29, Python `3.7.2`, `pandas` version `0.23.4` and `IPython` version `6.5.0`, all installed using `conda`.

Comment: The line `d.xs('2018', level=1, drop_level=False)` fails with `KeyError: '2018'` for me ...

Comment: Same here.... I am not sure that .xs supports 'partial string indexing'.

Comment: If each date in the table have a different year, it works fine... weird!